# How to check if an offset is there in an ISO date string

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, iso8601

Given a ISO string like this

```
String dateTime = "2016-07-11T16:50:22.00+05:00";
```

Is there a way to find an offset is present in the specific string or not using joda?

This is what the code i have done so far, to get an offset if one is present

```
public static String getDateTimeWithTimeZoneOffset(String dateTimeString)
    {
        DateTimeFormatter df = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().withOffsetParsed();
        DateTime nDt = df.parseDateTime(dateTimeString);
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatterWithoutMillis = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        return dateFormatterWithoutMillis.print(nDt) + SPACE + nDt.getZone();
    }
```

the above code gives the below output

> 2016-07-11T16:50:22 +05:00

but when I have a string without an offset, like this one below

> 2016-07-11T16:50:22

The same code takes in a default time zone and prints like this

> 2016-07-11T16:50:22 America/Chicago

is there anyway i can check if an offset is present in the string or not, if not throw an exception?

Comment: Use Regular Expressions?

Comment: Well you could start by checking the length... the minimum-length offset is 1 character ("Z") so assuming the rest is always yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss, you can tell if there's definitely no offset.

Comment: @striker Jon Skeet has got it. This is the cheapest way w/o parsing it. Consider that offset can be `Z`, `-05`, `-05:00`. Btw, offset for `America/Chicago` is negative and not positive. Something is fishy with your output/code.

Comment: Sure that sounds reasonable, but in my case the string can have milliseconds as well. so the formats can be with millisec --> "2016-07-11T16:50:22.000"  without milli sec -->"2016-07-11T16:50:22" , basically the time part can change, I intially wrote a computation logic that finds the offset out of the string by spliting the string at the "T" char and from the second part of the string i.e. timepart find out "-" or "+" is present, but i was wondering if there is anyother way to achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) development team advises migration to java.time classes:

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310).

the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` as well as the highly successful 3rd-party [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### `OffsetDateTime`

The [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class represents a moment on the timeline with an assigned [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). The offset is represented by the [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) class.

## `LocalDateTime`

If your input string lacks any offset or time zone info, it is considered to be a “local” date-time. That means it is *not* a particular moment on the timeline, but rather a rough idea about a possible moment. Has no real meaning until you apply an offset or time zone.

The [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class handles this kind of value.

### ISO 8601

Your input string happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for date-time text formats.

The java.time classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings that represent date-time values. So, you can directly parse the input string without defining a formatting pattern.

### Example code

The strategy here is to try parsing as if the input string includes an offset. If not, an exception ([`DateTimeParseException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html)) is thrown. In that case, we try parsing again but as a [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) value. If that second attempt throws a parsing exception, then the input is completely unexpected.

Some coding-fundamentalists will protest this use of nested exception testing. While I understand their concerns as this approach can be abused, in this particular kind of situation I maintain nested exception testing is acceptable, logical, and clear.

```
String input = "2016-07-11T16:50:22.00"; // "2016-07-11T16:50:22.00+05:00";
Boolean hasOffset = null;
try {
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( input );
    hasOffset = Boolean.TRUE;
    ZoneOffset offset = odt.getOffset ();
    System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | hasOffset: " + hasOffset + " | odt: " + odt + " | offset: " + offset );
} catch ( java.time.format.DateTimeParseException e1 ) {
    // Perhaps input lacks offset-from-UTC. Try parsing as a local date-time.
    try {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse ( input );
        hasOffset = Boolean.FALSE;
        System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | hasOffset: " + hasOffset + " | ldt: " + ldt );
    } catch ( java.time.format.DateTimeParseException e2 ) {
        System.out.println ( "ERROR - Unexpected format in the input string" ); // FIXME: Handle format exception.
    }
}
```

When run with `2016-07-11T16:50:22.00+05:00`.

> input: 2016-07-11T16:50:22.00+05:00 | hasOffset: true | odt: 2016-07-11T16:50:22+05:00 | offset: +05:00

When run with `2016-07-11T16:50:22.00`.

> input: 2016-07-11T16:50:22.00 | hasOffset: false | ldt: 2016-07-11T16:50:22

### Length testing

Of course you could always test the length of the input string. Given your example inputs, those with offsets will be longer than those without. Such length-testing can be brittle or error-prone if you have multiple kinds of input.

Comment: The problem with your code is, that catching the first DateTimeParseException is part of the normal program flow. if we expect strings without timezone we should check and prevent the exception.

Comment: @dermoritz What exactly is wrong with catching the first exception as a way of detecting a given format? Does it really make sense to replicate all the date-time formatting code from existing classes to externally test the given input? That seems like a crazy misapplication of the general rule to avoid excessive use of exceptions in guiding program control flow. Not driving your program by exceptions is a good rule *in general*, but checking an input against a series of expected formats using code already written and tested, with an exception signifying pass/fail, is perfectly sensible to me.

Comment: it is not really your fault but a fault in api (there should be a way to give a default time zone). The problem with exceptions is, that they have a massive performance impact (Joshua Bloch:Effective Java, Item 57 ). I implemented it exactly the way you did - on a search for the problem i found this post. I will stick to this code until i found a better way - and replicating code is not a better way.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
String dateWithoutMillis = dateFormatterWithoutMillis.print(nDt) + SPACE + nDt.getZone();
if (dateWithoutMillis.contains("/") {
  throw new InvalidDateStringException("NO OFFSET");
} else {
  return dateWithoutMillis
}
```

And don't forget to add the Exception:

```
public static class InvalidDateStringException extends Exception {

    public InvalidDateStringException(String message){
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if your solution is on a String date = "2016-07-11T16:50:22" which is from an UTC time zone, but the string doesnt have time zone attached to it, i think it wont catch this right? @hulk

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
if(dateTimeString.matches(".*(\\+|-)\\d{2}(:?\\d{2})?$")){
    // has offset.
}
```

[HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMLU5mOTJiNzdjY2c) is an example.

Comment: the string Z at the end of the date also contains timezone information, namely UTC. This is not handled here.